# Cannot install aptitude

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, aptitude

If I try to install aptitude, (with `sudo apt-get install aptitude`) I get:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.8.10-6ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-filesystem1.65.1 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-iostreams1.65.1 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-system1.65.1 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3v5 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libsigc++-2.0-0v5 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libxapian30 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: libparse-debianchangelog-perl but it is not going to be installed
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-418 (>= 418.67) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-dkms-418 (>= 418.67) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-driver-418 (>= 418.67) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-418 (>= 418.67) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-418 (>= 418.67) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: nvidia-utils-418 (>= 418.67) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 (>= 418.67) but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-gl-418 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-430 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-430 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-430 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

which doesn't get fixed with the suggested `apt --fix-broken install`, as I have an issue with other drivers. It returns:

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 ocl-icd-libopencl1 xserver-xorg-legacy
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-430 libnvidia-gl-430 nvidia-compute-utils-418 nvidia-compute-utils-430 nvidia-dkms-418 nvidia-dkms-430 nvidia-driver-418 nvidia-driver-430
  nvidia-kernel-common-418 nvidia-kernel-common-430 nvidia-kernel-source-418 nvidia-kernel-source-430 nvidia-utils-418 nvidia-utils-430
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430
Recommended packages:
  libnvidia-compute-430:i386 libnvidia-decode-430:i386 libnvidia-encode-430:i386 libnvidia-ifr1-430:i386 libnvidia-fbc1-430:i386 libnvidia-gl-430:i386
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  nvidia-418 nvidia-418-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-cfg1-430 libnvidia-gl-430 nvidia-compute-utils-418 nvidia-compute-utils-430 nvidia-dkms-418 nvidia-dkms-430 nvidia-driver-418 nvidia-driver-430
  nvidia-kernel-common-418 nvidia-kernel-common-430 nvidia-kernel-source-418 nvidia-kernel-source-430 nvidia-utils-418 nvidia-utils-430
  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-430
0 upgraded, 16 newly installed, 2 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 228 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 117044 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-430_430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libnvidia-gl-430:amd64 (430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-430_430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/10_nvidia.json', which is also in package nvidia-418 418.67-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-430_430.40-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164480/ubuntu-19-04-problems-install-upgrades

Comment: first aid `sudo mv  /usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/10_nvidia.json /usr/share/glvnd/egl_vendor.d/10_nvidia.json.bak` and try again.