# sub-process - apt-listchanges error

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, python3

I keep on getting this error when I try to install or upgrades and almost every thing.

```
After this operation, 731 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/apt-listchanges: not found
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10
```

Output for `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges`:

```
DPkg::Pre-Install-Pkgs { "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10"; };

DPkg::Tools::Options::/usr/bin/apt-listchanges::Version "2";
```

Output for `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`:

```
    Errors were encountered while processing:

     python3

     python3-crypto

     lsb-release

    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (

output for sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt install -f

Hit:2 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid InRelease

Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease

Hit:3 http://kali.download/kali kali-bleeding-edge InRelease

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

1 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Setting up python3 (3.7.3-1) ...

running python rtupdate hooks for python3.7...

dpkg-query: package 'apt-listchanges' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>

    main()

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main

    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))

  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package

    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)

Exception: cannot get content of apt-listchanges


error running python rtupdate hook apt-listchanges

dpkg-query: package 'backdoor-factory' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>

    main()

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main

    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))

  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package

    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)

Exception: cannot get content of backdoor-factory

error running python rtupdate hook backdoor-factory

dpkg-query: package 'dh-python' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>

    main()

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main

    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))

  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package

    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)

Exception: cannot get content of dh-python

error running python rtupdate hook dh-python

dpkg-query: package 'gedit' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>

    main()

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))

  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package

    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)

Exception: cannot get content of gedit

error running python rtupdate hook gedit

dpkg-query: package 'system-config-printer-common' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>

    main()

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main

    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))

  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)
Exception: cannot get content of system-config-printer-common

error running python rtupdate hook system-config-printer-common
dpkg-query: package 'terminator' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))

  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)

Exception: cannot get content of terminator

error running python rtupdate hook terminator

dpkg-query: package 'veil' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()

  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))

  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package

    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)

Exception: cannot get content of veil

error running python rtupdate hook veil

dpkg-query: package 'virtualbox' is not installed

Use dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list archive files contents.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 210, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/py3clean", line 196, in main
    pfiles = set(dpf.from_package(options.package))
  File "/usr/share/python3/debpython/files.py", line 53, in from_package
    raise Exception("cannot get content of %s" % package_name)

Exception: cannot get content of virtualbox

error running python rtupdate hook virtualbox
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):

 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error 
exit status 4

Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please run `ls /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/ | grep listchanges` and add the output

Comment: the output is 20listchanges

Comment: Please run `cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges` and add the output to your question by editing it: https://askubuntu.com/posts/1166037/edit

Comment: done .. what next :(

Comment: Please try option # 3

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is installed. Your repositories do not show Ubuntu repositories. If you are not running Ubuntu, this question might be off-topic and we can't answer it here. Please read: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 3):

**Option # 1:**

Please try:

```
sudo apt purge -f apt-listchanges
```

Then try:

```
sudo apt install -f apt-listchanges
```

---

**Option # 2:**

Please try:

```
sudo dpkg --remove apt-listchanges
```

Then try:

```
sudo apt install -f apt-listchanges
```

**Option # 3:**

Please try:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20listchanges.bak
```

Then try:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: i tried both options , it still giving me the same error

Comment: @KuraCatalony I updated the answer with a third option. Please try it and let me know if `apt` works again.

Comment: it worked perfectly but in the last step i got this error : Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 python3-crypto
 lsb-release
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @KuraCatalony Please try `sudo dpkg --configure -a` then try `sudo apt update –fix-missing` then try `sudo apt install -f` . If still not updating, please try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501

Comment: i tried those options too.. and i posted the result above please check it out !

Comment: @KuraCatalony Please try `sudo dpkg --remove apt-listchanges` then try `sudo apt purge -f apt-listchanges` then try `sudo apt install aptitude` then try `sudo aptitude install python3` then try `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update –fix-missing && sudo apt install -f`