# Package system Is Broken 19.04 (Disco Dingo)

Tags: system-installation, software-installation, dpkg

I have a new installation, ran two commands in a terminal
- sudo apt update
- sudo apt upgrade
Let it do it's thing.
restored some data (that was a day I'll never get back)
today I was tryng to install some programmes (VLC, Xine, Strawberry, K3b) they all failed to install from the Software Manager (including the snap catalogue)
Then an orange dot appeared next to the Network Manager icon and whn I clicked on it to see what it was it said

```
> The package system is broken Check if you are using third party
> repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of
> problems. Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get
> install -f Transaction failed: The package system is broken  The
> following packages have unmet dependencies:
> 
> kio: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0) but 1:9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04 is
> installed
>      Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed libk3b7: Depends: libkf5cddb5 (>= 4:18.12.3~) but 4:18.12.3-0ubuntu1
> is installed
>          Depends: libmpcdec6 (>= 1:0.1~r435) but 2:0.1~r495-1build1 is installed
>          Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.5.0~) but it is not installed libkf5attica5: Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not
> installed libkf5cddb5: Depends: libkf5cddb-data (= 4:18.12.3-0ubuntu1)
> but 4:18.12.3-0ubuntu1 is installed
>              Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.6.1~) but it is not installed libkf5kiocore5: Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it
> is not installed libkf5kiofilewidgets5: Depends: libqt5network5 (>=
> 5.8.0~) but it is not installed libkf5kiowidgets5: Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed
> libkf5newstuffcore5: Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not
> installed libkf5xmlgui-bin: Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it
> is not installed libkf5xmlgui5: Depends: libkf5xmlgui-data (=
> 5.56.0-0ubuntu2) but 5.56.0-0ubuntu2 is installed
>                Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed
>                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-2 but it is a virtual package libqt5gui5: Depends: libgbm1 (>= 8.1~0) but 19.0.8-0ubuntu0~19.04.1 is
> installed
>             Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4) but 1:9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04 is installed
>             Depends: libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0) but 2:1.0.9-2 is installed
>             Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu8 is installed
>             Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed
>             Depends: libudev1 (>= 183) but 240-6ubuntu5.7 is installed
>             Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-2 but it is a virtual package
>             Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1ubuntu2 is installed libqt5qml5: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4) but
> 1:9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04 is installed
>             Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not installed
>             Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-2 but it is a virtual package libqt5quick5: Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not
> installed
>               Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-2 but it is a virtual package
>               Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-12-2 but it is a virtual package libqt5webkit5: Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.0) but
> 1:9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04 is installed
>                Depends: libicu63 (>= 63.1-1~) but 63.1-6 is installed
>                Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu8 is installed
>                Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.9.0~beta) but it is not installed
>                Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 6) but 9.1.0-2ubuntu2~19.04 is installed
>                Depends: qtbase-abi-5-12-2 but it is a virtual package
>                Depends: qtdeclarative-abi-5-12-2 but it is a virtual package
>                Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1ubuntu2 is installed qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2: Depends: libkf5kirigami2-5
> (= 5.56.1-0ubuntu1) but 5.56.1-0ubuntu1 is installed
>                               Depends: libqt5network5 (>= 5.8.0~) but it is not installed
```

I checked that I didn't install any 3rd party repos in my sleep - I didn't 
So ran the suggested command - no change.
Rebooted - the dot telling me the system is broken remains

Googling suggested that I try to reconfigure dpkg with "sudo dpkg --configure -a"

this threw up a lot of activity in the terminal that finished with ---

```
> dpkg: too many errors, stopping Processing triggers for libc-bin
> (2.29-0ubuntu2) ... Errors were encountered while processing: 
> libkf5xmlgui-bin  libkf5kiowidgets5:amd64  libkf5newstuff5:amd64 
> libqt5gui5:amd64  libqt5quickcontrols2-5:amd64  libqt5svg5:amd64 
> libqt5widgets5:amd64  libqt5webkit5:amd64  libkf5xmlgui5:amd64 
> libkf5textwidgets5:amd64  qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2 
> qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64  libkf5iconthemes-bin 
> libqt5waylandclient5:amd64  libqt5quickwidgets5:amd64 
> libqt5waylandcompositor5:amd64  libqt5printsupport5:amd64 
> libkf5kirigami2-5  libkf5configgui5:amd64  libkf5declarative5:amd64 
> libkf5kiofilewidgets5:amd64  libkf5globalaccel5:amd64 
> libkf5quickaddons5:amd64  libkf5kiogui5:amd64  k3b 
> libkf5kiocore5:amd64  libqt5qml5:amd64  libk3b7-extracodecs 
> libkf5newstuffcore5:amd64  libkf5kcmutils5:amd64 
> qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:amd64  libkf5globalaccelprivate5:amd64 
> libkf5sonnetui5:amd64  libkf5crash5:amd64  libkf5waylandclient5:amd64 
> libqt5webchannel5:amd64  libkf5wallet-bin  keditbookmarks  kio 
> libkf5cddb5  libk3b7  libkf5notifyconfig5:amd64 
> qml-module-qtqml-models2:amd64  libqt5quicktemplates2-5:amd64 
> libkf5bookmarks5:amd64  libkf5parts-plugins  libdbusmenu-qt5-2:amd64 
> libkf5completion5:amd64  libkf5windowsystem5:amd64 
> qml-module-qtquick2:amd64  libkf5iconthemes5:amd64 Processing was
> halted because there were too many errors.
```

So I started this project a week ago and here I am so close but it's still unusable

Apart from going through the agony of re-saving the data, a completely new installation, restoring my data and then (probably getting the exact same error) what can I do to start enjoying this exciting new Ubuntu experience ?

Comment: To check if any 3rd party repositories are present, please run in the terminal `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and [edit] your question to add the output. Meanwhile, you can try and fix the broken packages following the steps in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501

Comment: I've spent an hour trying to boot to Grub menu - can't do it. Fast boot is off in BIOS hold down left Shift - boots to O/S, reboot hold down right Shift - boots to O/S

Comment: :) It can be a bit tricky. Hold the left Shift key as soon as your system boots and check this link: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: That's exactly what I have been doing, as soon as the BIOS screen appaears my finger hovers over the shift key *immediately* it is gone I depress that key

Comment: Before it is gone... and keep holding the Shift key

Comment: Also if you interrupt the boot process early by pressing Ctrl + Alt + Delet together, the system will reboot into GRUB menu directly.

Comment: So ...rebuilt GRUB (that's probably why no amount of <Shift> or Alt+Ctrl+Del gave me any option.

Comment: instead I got the exact same output sudo dpkg --configure -a
[sudo] password for Saywot: 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libkf5xmlgui-bin
 libkf5kiowidgets5:amd64
 libkf5newstuff5:amd64
 libqt5gui5:amd64
 libqt5quickcontrols2-5:amd64
 libqt5svg5:amd64
 libqt5widgets5:amd64
 libqt5webkit5:amd64
 libkf5xmlgui5:amd64
 libkf5textwidgets5:amd64
 qml-module-org-kde-kirigami2
 qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64
 libkf5iconthemes-bin
 libqt5waylandclient5:amd64
 libqt5quickwidgets5:amd64
 libqt5waylandcompositor5:amd64
 Processing was halted because there were too many errors.