# E:The package python3-software-properties needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it

Tags: package-management

This is the message i read;can you help me and excuse my bad English?
Thanks a lot for all you can do...
What i have done is following:
In the terminal:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install --reinstall python3-apt
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait

E: Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier verrou /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission non accordée)
E: Impossible de verrouiller le répertoire /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission non accordée)
W: Problème de suppression du lien /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission non accordée)
```

what can I do?

Comment: Try removing the the apt lock by running in the terminal `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` then run `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`.  Please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501) for help.