# Unable to run apt --fix-broken install to install required dependencies due to broken pipe error

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, dpkg

I am told I am missing the dependency: `libcublas-dev` . I am suggested to use `sudo apt --fix-broken install`. However, when I run this I receive an error about the paste subprocess being killed by signal (Broken pipe).

I have also tried directly installing the dependency and also receive a broken pipe error.

Here is the output I receive. I have read some similar topics about overwriting a .deb file but did not have any luck with them.

```
~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-liberation2 fonts-opensymbol gir1.2-geocodeglib-1.0
  gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 gir1.2-gudev-1.0
  gir1.2-udisks-2.0 grilo-plugins-0.3-base gstreamer1.0-gtk3 libatomic1:i386
  libboost-date-time1.65.1 libboost-filesystem1.65.1 libboost-iostreams1.65.1
  libboost-locale1.65.1 libbsd0:i386 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1v5
  libclucene-core1v5 libcmis-0.5-5v5 libcolamd2 libdazzle-1.0-0
  libdrm-amdgpu1:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-nouveau2:i386
  libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm2:i386 libe-book-0.1-1 libedataserverui-1.2-2
  libedit2:i386 libelf1:i386 libeot0 libepubgen-0.1-1 libetonyek-0.1-1
  libevent-2.1-6 libexiv2-14 libexpat1:i386 libffi6:i386 libfreerdp-client2-2
  libfreerdp2-2 libgc1c2 libgee-0.8-2 libgexiv2-2 libgl1:i386
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libglapi-mesa:i386 libglvnd0:i386 libglx-mesa0:i386
  libglx0:i386 libgom-1.0-0 libgpgmepp6 libgpod-common libgpod4
  liblangtag-common liblangtag1 liblirc-client0 libllvm9:i386 liblua5.3-0
  libmediaart-2.0-0 libmspub-0.1-1 libnvidia-common-430 libnvidia-common-435
  libodfgen-0.1-1 libpciaccess0:i386 libqqwing2v5 libraw16 librevenge-0.0-0
  libsensors4:i386 libsgutils2-2 libssh-4 libstdc++6:i386
  libsuitesparseconfig5 libvncclient1 libwinpr2-2 libx11-6:i386
  libx11-xcb1:i386 libxapian30 libxau6:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386
  libxcb-dri3-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386
  libxcb1:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxdmcp6:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxmlsec1 libxmlsec1-nss libxshmfence1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386
  linux-headers-4.15.0-74 linux-headers-4.15.0-74-generic
  linux-headers-5.0.0-23 linux-headers-5.0.0-23-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-74-generic linux-image-5.0.0-23-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-74-generic linux-modules-5.0.0-23-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-74-generic linux-modules-extra-5.0.0-23-generic
  lp-solve media-player-info python3-mako python3-markupsafe syslinux
  syslinux-common syslinux-legacy usb-creator-common
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libcublas-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcublas-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 150 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/42.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 114 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 288268 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcublas-dev (10.2.2.89-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/nvblas.h', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev 9.1.85-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libcublas-dev_10.2.2.89-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164480/ubuntu-19-04-problems-install-upgrades/1164505#1164505

Comment: You haven't told us which release, and I can't tell as your packages are third-party sourced (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libcublas).  It's easier to help when provided all details.

Comment: Raffa's solution worked very well! Thanks so much. For future users: Specifically option 2 in the linked post involving the recovery mode is what fixed the issue.