# Terminal Errors with LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice

```
frederick@frederickpina:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libreoffice-base : Depends: libreoffice-common (>= 1:6.4.0~beta1-2~) but 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
                    Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 4.0.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                    Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
                    Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
 libreoffice-base-core : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                         Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                         Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-base-drivers : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                            Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                            Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-calc : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 4.0.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
                    Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
                    Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
 libreoffice-common : Breaks: libreoffice-core (>= 1:6.4~) but 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-style-tango (>= 1:6.4~) but 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
 libreoffice-core : Depends: libreoffice-common (> 1:6.4.2) but 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
                    Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 6.4.0~beta) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
                    Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-draw : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
                    Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
                    Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
 libreoffice-gnome : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                     Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 4.0.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                     Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                     Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                     Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-gtk3 : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 4.0.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                    Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-impress : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                       Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                       Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                       Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                       Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
                       Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
 libreoffice-java-common : Depends: libjuh-java but it is not installed
                           Depends: libjurt-java but it is not installed
                           Depends: libridl-java but it is not installed
                           Depends: libunoil-java but it is not installed
                           Depends: libunoloader-java but it is not installed
 libreoffice-math : Depends: libreoffice-core (= 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) but 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
 libreoffice-report-builder : Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
 libreoffice-report-builder-bin : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                                  Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 4.0.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                                  Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                                  Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                                  Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-sdbc-firebird : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                             Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                             Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.1.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                             Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                             Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-sdbc-mysql : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 4.2.0~rc1) but it is not installed
                          Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                          Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                               Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 4.0.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                               Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 4.1.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                               Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                               Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 libreoffice-writer : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                      Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                      Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
                      Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
                      Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
                      Breaks: libreoffice-common (< 1:6.4.2~rc1~) but 1:6.3.5-0ubuntu0.19.10.1 is installed
 python3-uno : Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
               Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
               Depends: uno-libs-private but it is not installed
 ure : Depends: uno-libs-private (= 1:6.4.2-0ubuntu0.19.10.1) but it is not installed
       Depends: libuno-cppu3 (>= 4.4.0~alpha) but it is not installed
       Depends: libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3 (>= 4.0.0~alpha) but it is not installed
       Depends: libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not installed
       Depends: libuno-sal3 (>= 5.3.0~alpha) but it is not installed
       Depends: libuno-salhelpergcc3-3 (>= 3.6.0~beta) but it is not installed
       Recommends: libjuh-java but it is not installed
       Recommends: libjurt-java but it is not installed
       Recommends: libridl-java but it is not installed
       Recommends: libunoloader-java but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
frederick@frederickpina:~$
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164480/ubuntu-19-04-problems-install-upgrades/1164505#1164505

Comment: Looks like you tried to install the wrong version of LibreOffice. If you are in the habit of using -y with apt, you are disabling protections that try to warn you about mistakes like these. Better to install the version in the Ubuntu repositories that's already tested to work with your release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with libreoffice-math. If you remove that one, the rest will install perfectly okay. Try this:

```
sudo dpkg --purge libreoffice-math libreoffice
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

That should fix it and the rest of all your LibreOffice apps should work just fine.