# Broken packages (cant install software)

Tags: upgrade, kernel

**I'm trying to install LAME mp3 decoder and I'm getting this...**

```
sudo apt-get install lame
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed
  lame
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 1 to remove and 413 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/45.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 156 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 288262 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic (4.4.0-141.167) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-141-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-141-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-141-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-141-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/casper-memdisk failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-141-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**I searched around the forum and ran this command ...**

```
sudo  dpkg -P --force-depends linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic
(Reading database ... 288262 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic (4.4.0-141.167) ...
Purging configuration files for linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic (4.4.0-141.167) ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
```

**Trying to install LAME again I get the same output...**

```
sudo apt-get install lame
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed
  lame
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 1 to remove and 413 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/45.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 156 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 288262 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic (4.4.0-141.167) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-141-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-141-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-141-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-141-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/casper-memdisk failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-141-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**I then listed 4.4.0-141 packages and tried to purge but didnt work...**

```
apt-cache pkgnames |grep 4.4.0-141
linux-headers-4.4.0-141
linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-141-lowlatency
linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-141
linux-tools-4.4.0-141
linux-signed-image-4.4.0-141-lowlatency
linux-headers-4.4.0-141-lowlatency
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-tools-4.4.0-141-generic
linux-tools-4.4.0-141-lowlatency
linux-image-4.4.0-141-lowlatency
linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic

sudo apt-get purge `!!`
sudo apt-get purge `apt-cache pkgnames |grep 4.4.0-141`
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-141' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-141-generic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-cloud-tools-4.4.0-141-lowlatency' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-141' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-141-generic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-headers-4.4.0-141-lowlatency' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-image-4.4.0-141-lowlatency' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-signed-image-4.4.0-141-lowlatency' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-4.4.0-141' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-4.4.0-141-generic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'linux-tools-4.4.0-141-lowlatency' is not installed, so not removed
The following packages will be REMOVED
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-141-generic*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 2 to remove and 413 not to upgrade.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 156 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 288262 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic (4.4.0-141.167) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-141-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-141-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-141-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-141-generic
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-141-generic
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-141-generic: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/casper-memdisk failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-141-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Ive done a lot of searching but can only find posts that have some of the error lines that Im getting. Its beyound me to try and link everything together.
Ive also tried to use package manager to remove broken dependences but it end up giving me the same  error : E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

**Finally I tried this to see what it gives...**

```
ls -al /boot
total 214512
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Apr  2 19:59 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root     4096 Jan 19  2019 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1166991 Dec  4  2017 abi-3.13.0-137-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1168825 Jun 14  2018 abi-3.13.0-153-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1169147 Dec  5  2018 abi-3.13.0-164-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  1164671 May 20  2015 abi-3.13.0-53-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   166050 Dec  4  2017 config-3.13.0-137-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   166136 Jun 14  2018 config-3.13.0-153-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   166221 Dec  5  2018 config-3.13.0-164-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   165762 May 20  2015 config-3.13.0-53-generic
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Jan  1  1970 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Mar 18 14:42 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 30940994 Dec 20  2017 initrd.img-3.13.0-137-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 30184136 Dec 31  2018 initrd.img-3.13.0-153-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 31778569 Jan 16  2019 initrd.img-3.13.0-164-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 30801564 Dec 20  2017 initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 29409680 Nov 22  2017 initrd.img-3.13.0-53-generic.old-dkms
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      691 Jun 14  2018 retpoline-3.13.0-153-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root      254 Dec  5  2018 retpoline-3.13.0-164-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3400567 Dec  4  2017 System.map-3.13.0-137-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3414641 Jun 14  2018 System.map-3.13.0-153-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3417774 Dec  5  2018 System.map-3.13.0-164-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  3390132 May 20  2015 System.map-3.13.0-53-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5852400 Dec  4  2017 vmlinuz-3.13.0-137-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5854328 Dec 20  2017 vmlinuz-3.13.0-137-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root  5893168 Jun 14  2018 vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5895096 Aug 12  2018 vmlinuz-3.13.0-153-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root  5905712 Dec  5  2018 vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5907640 Jan 10  2019 vmlinuz-3.13.0-164-generic.efi.signed
-rw-------  1 root root  5821152 May 20  2015 vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  5823064 Dec 20  2017 vmlinuz-3.13.0-53-generic.efi.signed
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: A quick scan of your initial output shows at least FIVE separate errors, each of which would prevent what you want to accomplish. Consider a complete reinstall as the simplest solution. If you want to fix all the problems, consider a thread at our sister site ubuntuforums.org. They specialize in step-by-step troubleshooting and handholding. This site is not well suited to the kind of support that you seem to need.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501

Comment: Could I ask if you solved this issue?