# cannot upgrade or fix broken install

Tags: upgrade, dependencies, linux-headers

On Ubuntu 18.04
 Upgrade gives

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    linux-headers-5.3.0-45-generic : Depends: linux-headers-5.3.0-45 but it is not installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

--fix broken install gives EOF error

Comment: Related answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I had tried to post this earlier, but it did not post and I fixed the problem before it posted.  I figured I would still post it and how it was fixed.

Apparently, some files in the apt cache folder were damaged.
So I followed theses steps:

Clear the apt cache

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Update the list of available software packages

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Try to finish all pending installations

```
sudo apt-get -f install

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Try the upgrade again

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Note:
I would proceed with the next step only if the previous step had succeeded.