# Trouble installing BleachBit

Tags: grub2, xorg, dpkg, lightdm, bleachbit

I have ubuntu 18.04 LTS and I'm wanting to get BleachBit and when I try through the command line, I get this error message:

```
 Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 168709 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic (4.15.0-20.21) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This is what's in Xorg.0.log:

```
[  2545.601] _XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
[  2545.602] _XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
[  2545.602] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[  2545.603] (EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
[  2545.603] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[  2545.604] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  2545.604] (EE) 
[  2545.604] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I used `sudo service lightdm stop` to try to kill the xserver and got "Failed to stop lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service not loaded."

When I try installing from the website, I get this error message in a notification: "Unable to install BleachBit: Error while installing package: installed linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1"

So I'm at a loss here. I didn't find anything that could help me when I looked up the error messages. I've also had this same command line error when trying to install ffmpeg as well. I would greatly appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

EDIT: I went to wiki.x.org, to https://www.x.org/wiki/FAQErrorMessages/ and it said to try `netstat -ln` but command netstat was not found, and I got the same error message when trying to install it.

EDIT2: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` returns:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180426)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

EDIT3: `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing -y && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` returns:

```
Setting up linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) ...
Processing triggers for linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (4.15.0-29.31) ...
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-29-generic
/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub:
_XSERVTransSocketUNIXCreateListener: ...SocketCreateListener() failed
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: server already running
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Cannot establish any listening sockets - Make sure an X server isn't already running(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
(EE) 
(EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-29-generic
```

EDIT4: Output of `cat /etc/default/grub` is:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
X
sudo update-grub
X

X

sudo update-grub
```

Comment: try `sudo apt install --reinstall xorg` first then install with `sudo apt install bleachbit` and see if it helps.

Comment: I get the same error message when I try that too.

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: I added it in a new edit on main post.

Comment: try `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing -y && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y`

Comment: It gives me the same error messages.

Comment: Try `sudo mv /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub.old` then run `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing -y && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` again

Comment: Keep getting the same errors.

Comment: I have other options but they are a bit risky. The safest option I could think of is to follow option #2 in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501) and see if it helps.

Comment: If not fixed yet, please add the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` there might be some missing or extra characters there.

Comment: I tried the second option in that and I got to the part where it tried to enable networking. I don't know how long it was supposed to take, but I waited about 10 minutes and decided to reboot because it stayed on the black screen and an options menu never came up. I don't know how long I'm supposed to wait, but it seemed like it shouldn't've taken that long. I've also added the newest output in the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some lines in your `/etc/default/grub` file which are not supposed to be in it and this results in an error when your system tries to parse it.

To fix this error, please remove this from your `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
X
sudo update-grub
X

X

sudo update-grub
```

So it contains only this:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash intel_idle.max_cstate=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Then run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing -y && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
```

Then install BleachBit like so:

```
sudo apt install bleachbit
```

---

**Notice:**

If the error persists after that, then run:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xorg
```

and try installing again.

Best of luck

Comment: When I tried changing the file, I got a notification that said "You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again."

Comment: @Shempklong Try editing with `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` then to save press `Ctrl + x` then press `Y` then press `Enter`

Comment: It worked, I was able to install BleachBit after that. Thanks for all your help and your patience. Marking this as the answer.

Comment: @Shempklong Well done : ) and you are most welcome.

Comment: Hi, I was having another issue with my display after a login loop and was wondering if you knew how to help. My question about it is here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225665/screen-stuck-on-zoom-after-fixing-login-loop