# Screen stuck on zoom after fixing login loop

Tags: command-line, nvidia, gnome, login

My power went out last night and I got in a login loop and that's when the screen zoom started. After a lot of searching and trying a lot of things, I found [this](https://support.system76.com/articles/login-loop/)
and tried making a new user with `sudo adduser test` and `sudo systemctl reboot` I was able to log into it and it was also zoomed in. I turned off zoom with `ctrl + windows/super + 8` and that didn't work. I also checked to see if zoom was disabled and it is. After that, I went back to tty and tried this from the link above and was able to log into my real account, but ~/.nvidia-setting-rc and ~/.nv were not found:

`mv ~/.config ~/.config.old
mv ~/.local ~/.local.old
mv ~/.cache ~/.cache.old
mv ~/.nvidia-settings-rc ~/.nvidia-settings-rc.old
mv ~/.nv ~/.nv.old
sudo systemctl reboot`

and:

`sudo apt install --reinstall gdm3 pop-desktop gnome-shell
sudo systemctl reboot`

When I logged back in, I got a welcome window from Ubuntu as if I just newly installed it, my toolbar on the side was back to default settings and the screen was still zoomed in, but I still have all my files and software from before. As far as I can tell, this zoom problem is the only issue I'm having right now. Everything else seems to work fine, I'm logged into it right now.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Output of `sudo lshw -C display` is:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: d
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

EDIT2: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-304 : Depends: xorg-video-abi-11 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-12 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-13 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-14 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-15 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-18 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-19 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-20 but it is not installable or
                       xorg-video-abi-23
              Depends: xserver-xorg-core
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

EDIT3: `sudo aptitude install nvidia-304` output:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcuda1-304{a} libxnvctrl0{a} nvidia-304 
  nvidia-opencl-icd-304{a} nvidia-settings{a} 
  ocl-icd-libopencl1{a} pkg-config{a} screen-resolution-extra{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1{u} gir1.2-keybinder-3.0{u} 
  libkeybinder-3.0-0{u} libpango1.0-0{u} libpangox-1.0-0{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 5 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 48.7 MB of archives. After unpacking 217 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl-mesa0 : Breaks: nvidia-304 but 304.137-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libglx-mesa0 : Breaks: nvidia-304 but 304.137-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     nvidia-304 [Not Installed]                         



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-opencl-icd-304{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1{a} 
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1{u} gir1.2-keybinder-3.0{u} 
  libkeybinder-3.0-0{u} libpango1.0-0{u} libpangox-1.0-0{u} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 5 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,441 kB of archives. After unpacking 17.2 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Get: 1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 ocl-icd-libopencl1 amd64 2.2.11-1ubuntu1 [30.3 kB]
Get: 2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 nvidia-opencl-icd-304 amd64 304.137-0ubuntu2 [5,411 kB]
Fetched 5,441 kB in 5s (1,135 kB/s)                
(Reading database ... 174633 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 (12.10.1+18.04.20180322.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Removing gir1.2-keybinder-3.0 (0.3.2-1) ...
Removing libkeybinder-3.0-0:amd64 (0.3.2-1) ...
Removing libpango1.0-0:amd64 (1.40.14-1ubuntu0.1) ...
Removing libpangox-1.0-0:amd64 (0.0.2-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 174608 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ocl-icd-libopencl1_2.2.11-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 (2.2.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-opencl-icd-304.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-opencl-icd-304_304.137-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-opencl-icd-304 (304.137-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 (2.2.11-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up nvidia-opencl-icd-304 (304.137-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

EDIT4: `sudo lshw -C display` output:

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: C61 [GeForce 6150SE nForce 430]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: d
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

EDIT5: `sudo apt install --fix-broken xorg-video-abi-11 xserver-xorg-core -y` output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package xorg-video-abi-11 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'xorg-video-abi-11' has no installation candidate
```

EDIT6: `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing -y && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` output:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease        
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease          
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]  
Get:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Ign:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

EDIT7: `sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update --fix-missing -y && sudo apt install -f -y && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` output:

```
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease        
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease             
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release [943 B]  
Get:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg [819 B]
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease     
Ign:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release.gpg
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 78BD65473CB3BD13
E: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106527/discussion-between-raffa-and-shempklong).