# Error: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: 18.04, apt, xubuntu, debian

```
root@tet0-Lenovo-G500s:/home/tet0/Downloads# apt install ./anydesk_5.5.4-1_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'anydesk:amd64' instead of './anydesk_5.5.4-1_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 anydesk:amd64 : Depends: libc6:amd64 (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libgcc1:amd64 (>= 1:4.1.1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.16.0) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libgtk2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.20.1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libstdc++6:amd64 (>= 4.1.1) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libx11-6:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb-shm0:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxcb1:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpango1.0-0:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libcairo2:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxrandr2:amd64 (>= 1.3) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libx11-xcb1:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxtst6:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxfixes3:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxdamage1:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libxkbfile1:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Depends: libgtkglext1:amd64 but it is not installable
                 Recommends: libglx-mesa0:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 19.04 problems install upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164480/ubuntu-19-04-problems-install-upgrades)

Comment: trying to install anydesk on  the wrong Ubuntu version? What is your "uname -a" ???

Comment: Linux tet0-Lenovo-G500s 5.3.0-46-generic #38~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 31 04:17:14 UTC 2020 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux   @kanehekili

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you've installed a 32 bit version of ubuntu. Then you need a 32 bit deb file - and you tried to install the 64 bit.
First you need to remove the "wrong" deb version.

Then update.

```
sudo apt update
```

Select and install the 32 bit deb version from Anydesk and you should be fine

Ubuntu will cease to support 32 bit. So it is a good idea to install a 64bit operating system on your Lenovo G500s (which has a 64 bit Windows by default)

Comment: okay thanks. where i can get debian 64 bit source file?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/h0bbel/4b28ede18d65c3527b11b12fa36aa8d1 take a look at this link. is that what i want to get?

Comment: I do not understand your question. If you want to setup a new ubuntu you can get the 64-bit ISO files where you've got your 32-bit iso files. If you didn't set up your laptop, you should ask the person who did. Otherwise I'd recommend to install the 32bit Version of anydesk.   If you can use my answer, accept it.