# Error while updating softwares 20.04

Tags: updates, 20.04, lock

I have a problem while trying update Ubuntu 20.04
How I can solve this?

[image: sudo apt update]

Comment: Wait a few minutes. It is being upgrading already.

Comment: Wait a few minutes as @Pilot6 says, it might be held by another APT process and is actually updating. If however this issue persists for a long time and no process number is shown anymore, try removing the lock as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501)