# Ubuntu 20.10 crash on boot

Tags: package-management, 20.10, recovery-mode

I was having problems with rgdal installation in R.

After reinstalling and rebooting, the system crashed!

I only see a black screen with:

```
/dev/sdb2: clean, 734088/7782400 files, 22665507/31127296 blocks

[FAILED] **Failed to start Service for snap application** canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.
[ 20160254] ocueoirt 0000:000:1c.5: AER: PCIe Bus Error: Severitz Corrected, type=Data link lazer, (transmitter ID)
[201.602640] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5: AER:  device [8086:9d151] error status/mask=00001000/0002000
[201.602713] pcieport 0000:00:1c.5 AER: [12] timeout
```

I tried to solve with the recovery mode, but it didn't help.

I entered recovery mode with network preferences and tried:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gdm3: depends gir1.2 .....gnome-shell, libgdm1, recomends libpam-fprint


E unable to correct problems, you have broken packages
```

I tried all the recovery menu options, then I activate network options and found aptitude in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/223267/1149324 :

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-desktop
```

The first attempt didn't work, then run again, didn't accept the first solution , but the second one. Rebooting and the system boots normally again.

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1164505/968501) to fix broken packages first. Hopefully, it will help.

Comment: Thanks for the help.