# Unable to insall pip on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, pip

Below are the screenshots for the error I see on the console

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: Please add text instead of screenshots. Copy and paste.

Comment: Hello @CharlesGreen i tried the fix mentioned in the thread, but it didnt work

Comment: @Raffa , now i am seeing the following error

Comment: @Raffa , now i am seeing the following error
sudo apt install python3-pip
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-wheel but it is not installable
Recommends: build-essential but it is not installable
Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Picture of text are very hard to read, and impossible to copy/paste from.  Please provide text (pasted into your question) in the future

Comment: If you have a new error message, tthat means progress!  Please look at [https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Good... previous issue is now fixed. Try the link by @CharlesGreen above or [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164480/ubuntu-19-04-problems-install-upgrades/1164505#1164505) to fix the new error.

Comment: To address a couple of comments above, if you have a screen full of text you can highlight it with your mouse, right click and copy it, then paste it into your questions above.  It can then be further formatted to make it much easier to read, and also to search through for specific messages.