# Ubuntu fails to boot, failed to activate swap, system logging service etc

Tags: boot, partitioning, swap, dbus

*Some hours ago I was using photorec to recover some files but this lead to it recovering everything ever deleted, which led to my hard drive being completely filled and me being stuck with an infinite loadscreen.*

*I used a bootable flash drive to gain ownership of the disk and deleted the files but i might have also deleted the swapfile.*

*Now I am getting a series of failed service texts after the loading screen this include:*

`[FAILED] Failed to start System Logging Service.`

`[FAILED] Failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus.`

`[FAILED] Failed to start Thermal Daemon Service.`

`[FAILED] Failed to start D-Bus System Hessage Bus.`

`[FAILED] Failed to start User Login Management.`

`[FAILED] Failed to start System Logging Service.`

Comment: Recovering deleted files on the same disk/partition as output destination is never a good idea ... Can you boot to rescue mode with networking as `root` and run `apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 19.04 problems install upgrades](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164480/ubuntu-19-04-problems-install-upgrades)

Comment: @Raffa I might be able to but I am worried if that can wipe out my user data, is there no other way to fix this problem?

Comment: @Raffa Update: I tried the reinstall through the process that you wrote about but there is an error in connecting, the message says that the connection was refused, I am basically stuck

Comment: No, you're not stuck ... Get into a root shell from a live system like this https://askubuntu.com/a/1238393 and fix your system by reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` ... Probably it's a good idea to **back up your important personal data** before attempting to fix.

Comment: @Raffa I tried backing it up but for some reason it could not transfer the files to the hard disk so I had to reinstall the whole ubuntu. Thank you very much for your help though, your advice helped quickened the process

Comment: It may be a mere coincidence but yesterday after I ran into some strange behavior* with a bootable USB ssd I was attempting to use to fix another system, I began receiving service failures starting with DBUS.  I've used this system for several years without needing to reinstall ubuntu and just attempted to do so about an hour ago (preserving user home directories) -- and it is still failing with pretty much the same symptoms.  

Was Ubuntu 24.04.2 and attempted to reinstall Ubuntu 24.04.2.

Comment: The "strange behavior" I observed was that upon ejecting the USB the storage remained in nautilus but without the eject icon beside it.  It was shortly thereafter that I entered service failure hell.