# Ubuntu won't boot. Frozen cursor in the top left

Tags: nvidia, 19.10, nomodeset, overclocking

I have been having difficulties with my Ubuntu installation.

It will no longer boot and shows a frozen cursor in the top left corner, I have checked many websites and have tried stuff like `nomodeset`, and I am able to access the console by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>. So I can apply terminal related fixes. I have lost my Ubuntu install USB so that is not an option. I have even tried changing session/display managers. Nothing has worked.

I am using Nvidia graphics cards. Ubuntu has been installed for two months and was working fine until now. This is on Ubuntu 19.10 with dev builds.

I was just installing nvidux or however it's spelled to attempt to overclock my PC's gpu. On reboot it is doing this now.

> I have tried many other posts and none of the methods I could do worked. Nomodeset was attempted and failed. I tried changing display managers, failed, and I tried clearing displays from xorg or whatever that was called. Failed, tried many others but forgot what they were. They all changed nothing
>
> I only have access to console so I can't attempt the boot repair tool or anything like that
>
> Booting from another kernel version gets stuck at "Started process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled" and then freezes. Power button works to turn off though

I have an image of it the cursor in the top left, but I can't post due to low reputation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: I have seen that post sadly. None of the methods in there listed worked so I decided to make a post

Comment: Thanks--I recommend that you **[edit]** this question to include full details about the methods you tried and exactly what happened. (You mentioned some things, like `nomodeset`, but I don't think there's currently enough detail here to facilitate an answer.) If there were methods that you didn't try because you had good reason to think they would not be reasonable, then I recommend including details about that as well.

Comment: Also, in your question you mentioned that you have an image which you can't add to your question. If you attempt to upload the image, you should get a link to it. If you comment with the link, someone can edit it in. (Feel free to ping me by including `@EliahKagan` in that or any other comments on this question for which you want the system to notify me; if no one else has added the image when I see it, I'll do so.)

Comment: Did you try booting earlier kernel versions in grub?

Comment: @CollierPlays You can upload the image file to a file host such as https://imgur.com/ then put the URL of your upload in your question with [edit].

Comment: @EliahKagan Updated my question

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall the desktop environment?

Comment: @MelcomX I have lost my installation media so that is currently not possible, is there any way to do it through ubuntu tty2? As that's my only tool I have to use.

Comment: Alright. I typed apt install ubuntu-desktop. And apparently SOMEHOW it was deleted. Will post as answer to question if this fixes it. Eta like 30 minutes

Comment: Sadly, it did not work. I attempted to do it, and it actually booted the login screen for a few seconds, i typed in my creds. and screen went black, only allowing tty. I tried rebooting but it now only booted to tty. I got my windows dualboot to boot so I am attempting fixes from windows

Comment: My system showed erratical boot behaviour, froze every other time after 19.10 upgrade. I found that the upgrade re-inserted the nouveau graphics drivers which caused this problem. Reinstalling Nvidia proprietary drivers solved the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with booting the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system)

Comment: sudo > /etc/X11/xorg.conf reboot