# After update to 18.04 the screen brightness slider stopped working

Tags: 18.04, updates, brightness

I am not 100% that it is related to the ->18.04 update, could be some other update.
Nevertheless, it was a coincidence in time with the release update, so I think it might be it.

In short, this functionality: 
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/display-brightness.html.en

is no longer working. 
I can move the slider, but brightness doesn't change. The keyboard shortcut works: it moves the slider, but the brightness doesn't change.
As a temporary solution I installed and use xbacklight, but it would be nice to be able to again control brightness with dedicated hotkeys.
Any advices? If nothing works, I will bind some other keys to xbacklights....

Comment: Do you have dual NVIDIA and INTEL graphics cards? If so, try purging the proprietary NVIDIA drivers and installing the `nouveau` driver (Open Source NVIDIA driver). This might be the cause.

Comment: I never knew it, checked only now. I have nvidia GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M] with the proprietary driver nvidia-driver-390. The specs does not say anything about it being dual.

Comment: Probably the installed driver is not compatible with the updated kernel. You could refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539/968501) for info and try in the terminal first this `sudo apt purge nvidia-*` then this `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` then reboot after that.

Comment: Also asked via https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2438852

Comment: I never even knew about dual cards, but now as I read about it, it seems that my CPU specification says about "Intel HD Graphics 4600", so maybe this laptop has two graphics processing units indeed.

Comment: @Raffa, I will try the solution you suggest (indeed it seems quite probable that this is exactly what happened), but after the coronavirus quarantine is over: I currently need my laptop to work remotely and can't risk screwing the drivers! ;-) Will post an update here if it worked. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Raffa for the solution. It did not work out of the box, i.e. when I applied it, it did not change anything, because it reinstalled the driver in the nvidia-driver-390 version. Raffa was nevertheless right about the source of the problem and this is what I did to fix it:

I first added the following PPA:
[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Then, I applied a fix to this bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1768050
and finally after:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-* && sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

I had a new version of the driver, i.e. nvidia-driver-415 installed, which works smoothly with my 4.15.0-101-generic kernel. Thanks!