# How can I free some space in /var/cache/archives/

Tags: dual-boot, apt, nvidia, disk-usage, cache

I have a dual boot laptop,in my first partition windows are installed and in the second one I have installed Ubuntu.

when I try to boot into Ubuntu, I face a message saying that:

> started user manager for UID 121

I did some search on that and I understood that I have to reinstall drivers for my NVIDIA GPU.

When I try to do it I face a message saying that:

> You don’t have enough space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.

I have tried everything... Any ideas ? How can I free some space at my archives?

Output for `df -h` picture:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106115/discussion-on-question-by-giorgos-marinos-how-can-i-free-some-space-in-var-cach).

Answer (score 5):

**First**, As it appears your root directory ( partition ) `/` is **100% full**. So you will need to free some space. Please boot into the **recovery mode** as described in the linked answer below and follow these steps one by one and check your disk space until you can see some free space:

1. Clean the apt cache:

```
sudo apt clean
```

2. Empty the `/tmp` directory:

```
sudo find /tmp/{*,.??*} -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

3. Delete old log files:

```
sudo find /var/log -type f -name "*.gz" -delete
```

4. Remove old kernels:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

5. List large files ( 1 GB or more ) and delete the least important ones:

```
sudo du -hca --time / | grep -E "^[0-9\.]*[G]"
```

---

**Then**, you can follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1163539/968501) to fix the issue preventing Ubuntu from booting into the desktop.

Best of luck

Comment: This saved my day. Thanks a lot!!