# can't boot UID 120 Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot

I have seen a similar question and tried their solutions but could not solve it.
This is where I get stuck. Please see the picture.

Using Ubuntu 18.04.

Thank You

PS:  this is the one solution I tried, but it didn't work.
[Problems with booting the system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system)

PPS: I also tried this solution but no luck [17.10 to 18.04 upgrade freezes during boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036242/17-10-to-18-04-upgrade-freezes-during-boot)
[image]

Comment: It would be useful to include some of the things you have tried, so that people responding here don't waste their time or yours suggesting them again ;-).  Knowing how those turned out also might help suggest the solution.  I recommend [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1443973/edit) your question with more details.  Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Good point. I added the solutions that I tried. No luck so far. Hopefully it is something the community can help me solve. Thanks again.

Comment: @heynnema Good afternoon Sir. you helped several times before. I saw your name popping up on similar rebooting solutions. I tried but  it did not work.  Would you please take a look at this one, if you have time? Thank You

Comment: Is this a newer installation of 18.04 or one that you’ve used for several years? Are you running this as a VirtualBox VM? What are the hardware specifications of the machine? From the look of the error, I wonder if the system has enough video memory for a GUI 

Comment: @matigo. None of the above. Being using for a couple of years with no issues whatsoever.  Then this AM boom it gets stuck.  I have also Windows on it.

Comment: @matigo  AOI 9020 Dell, old machine, but as I said it was working fine until yesterday.  Did not add any new program or update. So I am really not sure what is going on.

Comment: How full is the disk? If you’ve run out of space (remember that 5% of free space is set aside), then this issue can appear 

Comment: @matigo I looked into that, but no. The disk still has more than 50% of space left. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am still looking for a solutions. Anybody has any ideas? thank you