# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS gets stuck on boot after graphics driver update

Tags: drivers, 18.04, updates, graphics

I was attempting to run Luminar AI in the Virtual Machine with Windows 10. It gave me an error saying I needed to update the graphics driver.

I used terminal commands but I don't know which one I entered into the terminal.

Now when I try to boot, it goes to a flashing black screen with lines of text and hangs there.

I can boot into recovery mode and open up a terminal, but I don't know how to restore it.

It may have been the recommended Nvidia drivers for the 18.04 LTS.

However, I believe the computer said it has a VGA controller.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1163516/968501

Comment: The related link posted did the trick!! Thank you!!